# Trying to submit form data into database after payment is succeeded, with node js and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, stripe-payments

i have a project where I have a form where you can fill in a first- and last-name, and then the names will be uploaded to my MongoDB database, and then placed on another page in p-tags.

I have succeeded to get this done, however the problem is that I need a payment to be succeeded before the form data will be uploaded to my database.

Currently I have both the forms and javascript for the submit-form and the stripe-payment api.

First, I have the script for the stripe API, and I have the script for both saving and posting form data to/from db:

```
    // routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        stripePublishableKey: 'pk_test_51IVfPNLNmuMLNSTmFh4R5GIZMjnTTf4mQGy5UQRTam6vfooJWhyXIrT5tIclvgydZm1EYPfN1VgBBCZAN6Las1Ap007qYaR6zr'
    });
});

// charge route
app.post('/charge', (req,res)=>{
    const amount = 2500;
    
    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })
    .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: 'coviDON',
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id
    }))
    .then(charge => res.render('success'));
});

// the page where the form data will be submitted
app.get('/wall', (req, res) => {
    Covid.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .then((result)=>{
            res.render('wall', {covids: result})
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
});

// save form data to db and post to wallsite
app.post('/wall', (req, res) => {
    const covid = new Covid(req.body);

    covid.save()
        .then((result)=>{
            res.redirect('/wall');
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
});
```

Then, I have the index page where the two forms are placed:

```
<body>
    <div class="create-attribute">
        <form action="/wall" method="POST">
            <label for="first-name">First name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required>
            <br><br>
            <label for="last-name">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required>
            <button>Buy</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <form action="/charge" method="POST">
        <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
        class="stripe-button"
        data-key= "<%= stripePublishableKey %>"
        data-amount="2500"
        data-name="Web Development Ebook"
        data-description="Ebook written by Brad Traversy"
        data-image="/img/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        >
        </script>
        <script>
            // hide default stripe button
            document.getElementsByClassName('stripe-button-el')[0].style.display = 'none';
        </script>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-white btn-lg">Purchase for 25$</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

So, my goal and question is how I can connect these two together, so I have to press the stripe-button and pay the fee. After the payment is succeeded I want the submit-form to be processed so the data the user inputs will be stores to the db, and then posted to the wall-site in the p-tags??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're using [Legacy Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout), which has been deprecated for years. It is recommended that you not integrate this way, and instead prefer the new [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout). If this is an existing integration, you should consider [migrating](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration).

That said, if you want to do something like this you'll want to switch to the [custom configuration](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#integration) and leverage the [token/source function callbacks](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#required).